# Python IMAP - The order of UIDs

Tags: python, imap

I am trying to write a simple IMAP client, and I want to fetch one newest message. Message with UID 46345 is the newest one in my Inbox, an older message has UID 46346.  Because of that my code doesn't work as I expect it! Why isn't the newest message have the highest UID? Should I not rely the highest UID having the latest date?

```
_, data = imap.uid('search', None, "UNSEEN")    
latest_email_uid = data[0].split()[-1]
_, data = imap.uid('fetch', latest_email_uid, '(RFC822.HEADER)')
raw_email = data[0][1]
print raw_email
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think the IMAP protocol provides any guarantee that the message UIDs will be allocated in order from oldest message to newest. The UIDs can even change from time to time (generally if the IMAP server has to reindex the mailbox) as long as the UIDVALIDITY changes to notify clients of this fact. You have to look at the date headers on the messages (or perhaps IMAP INTERNALDATE if that's what you're interested in) and sort them yourself.

Comment: Ok. I am surprised that so many IMAP examples use something like `data[0].split()[-1]` to pull out the "latest" message... considering how unreliable it is.

Comment: "Latest" here is defined by the last one put into the mailbox.  Not the latest by date header.  Messages could be delayed or added to the mailbox for any innumerable reasons.  Roughly, the order is the order that the server received them.

Answer (score 3):

It is not guaranted to be in the order of date.

Suppose You have moved one oldest email from folder(Mailbox)  A to B and again moved  it back to A then it will be assigned with new uid value.

Comment: Indeed, they are in order they were added to the mailbox, which is not necessarily by date.  A message could've gotten "Stuck" for 3 days, and then show up, or a user may have moved a message from another mailbox.